# How do I close an open file?

Tags: c#, file

This button opens a text file which has error log information:

```
private void btnViewErrorLogFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(AppVars.ErrorLogFilePath);
}
```

When the user goes to do any processing in the application, I want to check whether the file is open or not, if it is open, then I want to close it. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is almost identical to what you're trying to do:
[Process.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx)

```
Process myProcess;

private void btnViewErrorLogFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myProcess.Start(AppVars.ErrorLogFilePath);
}

private void doSomething()
{
    if (!myProcess.HasExited)
    {
      myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
      myProcess.Close();
    }

    // Do whatever you need with the file
}
```

Shows how to check if it's running and how to close it.